# How to create "/<Controller>/{id1}/<Action>/{id2}" such route in razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I have a requirement where I have to create a route like `/Class/10/Student/134` to get an information of a student whose role id is 134 and whose class id is 10. How can I create such a route in Razor pages?

I have added the following route in Startup.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetStudentFromClass",
    template: "Class/{classId}/Student/{studentId?}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Class",
        action = "Student"
    }
);
```

and my pages directory structure is like

```
- /Pages
  - /Class
    - Student.cshtml
    - Student.cshtml.cs
```

In Student.cshtml, I have added this `@page "{classId:int}/Student/{studentId:int?}"` to first line

But it is not working. Any suggestions, where I did wrong?

Comment: Define a route with `url: "/Class/{id1}/Student/{id2}`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated my question. I tried your solution but it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried changing page "{classId:int}/Course/{courseId:int?}" for page "{classId:int}/Course/{studentId:Id?}"?. I did it with a controller class to accept the request and I had no problem with the mapRoute you used.

Comment: Your route works just fine (so long as its before the default or any other matching routes)

Comment: @AlbertoCh I tried but didn't work.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, it is just before the default route but didn't work.

Comment: I`ve searching for the page directive in Razor, maybe this link can help you: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing

Answer (score 0):

The `mapRoute` method is for defining MVC routes. Razor Pages routing is handled a little differently. You should only need to define a template as part of the `@page` directive. In this case, it should be:

```
@page "/Class/{classid:int}/Student/{studentid:int}"
```

There is no need to add anything to the Startup file.